# How to approach to Session-State refactoring

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm currently performing some code-review / refactoring on an 8year Asp.Net MVC solution that has been passed hand-by-hand to five developers... so there's every kind of code written in there.

In this specific step, I've to allow the session-state to be persisted on Redis (since we have the necessity to scale horizontally and add another frontend). I have the `Session` object used in ~800 points of the app and at my first try of setting the `SessionState` to `Redis`, I got an exception on a class that-s not Marked as serializable (I was aware of such a possible issue).

What I ask you, is: What's the best way to analyze the Session's stored object? I mean, yes I can :

- iterate on each find
- check if the object is serializable (and if not modify it if not)
- write an unit-test for future use

Am I missing a simpler approach?

Comment: What do you want to analyze the stored object for? The size? If it's serializable (well it has to be if it's already stored in session)?

Comment: Well for In-Proc state it's ok each kind of object... I think that on redis it's saved as string